# Object.mapObjectToArray is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have big problem with my code because I don't get what I do wrong with mapping an object. I still get message 'object.mapobjecttoarray is not a function''

```
var AppNo = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    var dataNodes = Object.mapObjectToArray(this.props.data, function(no, id) {
        return (
            <div key={id}>{no.name}</div>
        )
    });
    return (
        <div>
            {dataNodes}
        </div>
    );
}
});
var App = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        data: {
            no: {
                name: 'text 1'
            },
            non: {
                name: 'text 2'
            }
        }
    }
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <AppNo data={this.state.data} />
        </div>
    );
}
});

ReactDOM.render (<App />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Can somebody tell me whats wrong?

Comment: There is no such method as `mapObjectToArray`. What are you trying to do? If you want to loop through your props, you should use `map` method.

Comment: `this.props.data.map(function (obj) {...`

Comment: Even if I tried with .map I was getting same message in console ''this.props.data.map is not a function

Comment: Then `this.props.data` probably isn't an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over `object` not `array` and `objects` does not have `map` method. Create array in your `App` state and everything should be fine.

### Example of data

```
data: [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'text 1'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'text 2'
    }
]
```

Check this pen with your example - http://codepen.io/t1m0n/pen/EKpeve?editors=0010#

### Your example fixed

```
var AppNo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    var dataNodes = this.props.data.map(function(item) {
        return (
            <div key={item.id}>{item.name}</div>
        )
    });
    return (
        <div>
            {dataNodes}
        </div>
    );
}
});
var App = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        data: [
            {
                id: '1',
                name: 'text 1'
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                name: 'text 2'
            }
        ]
    }
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <AppNo data={this.state.data} />
        </div>
    );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) a few minutes ago I just did what you did :D and it works. Have a good day :)